# Add new functionality to Bokeh

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

I'm trying to use Bokeh node/edge graph visualizations.  I like most of what I've found thus far.   However, I'd like to use a different hover mode for tooltips.  From what I've found (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/graph.html under "Interaction Policies"), I can hover either with "NodesAndLinkedEdges" (which hovers over nodes and highlights the node and its incident edges) or "EdgesAndLinkedNodes" (which hovers over edges and highlights the edge and nodes incident to it).  Digging into the code itself (https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/models/graphs.py), I found "NodesOnly" (which hovers and highlights only the node).

However, I would like to highlight the edge or node that I'm hovering over and add tooltips with attribute information over it.  Unfortunately, none of the three cases I've found so far appear to support hovering over either nodes or edges.  I tried looking in the code for if I could extend it to create a "NodeOrEdge" instance, but the code I found doesn't appear to do anything other than create the class name, add a comment, and then "pass".  Clearly, something more is happening, but I can't see where (likely JavaScript?).

Does anyone know how to create a new version of GraphHitTestPolicy to Bokeh or get what I'd like out of it?

Comment: You're absolutely right, there's some JS involved. This functionality definitely deserves a GitHub feature request if you want to create one.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov, thanks for the suggestion.  I was writing up my feature request on GitHub when it referred me to two similar requests.  https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9036 describes someone requesting an extension beyond EdgesAndLinkedNodes.  That one describes how to edit the JS.  Then, https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8920 seems to argue that what I want is impossible because the nodes and edges would need to have the same hover tip columns (but I want different things displayed for nodes than edges).

Comment: Yes, you need the former one. The latter one just states that _a single_ HoverTool cannot handle it. But you can have more than one HoverTool.